# Using STL list container, a linked list as an attribute needed to be initialised?

Tags: c++

I am confused that when using the STL list as an attribute in a class, do we need to initialise the linked list within the constructor, and how do we release the memory back to the system using destructor? I understand the STL list has a desctrutor which automatically delete the linked list. However, my instructor asked us to include destructor for the class. So I am figuring out how should I deal with the list attribute.

So I have a Column class which contains a linked list of char as its attribute. So far I have:

```
class Column
{
   private:

   list<char> chars;
   list<char>::const_iterator itr;

   public:

   Column()
   {  
   }

   ~Column()
   {
   }
.....
};
```

So do I need to initialise the linked list chars inside the constructor, and do I need to delete the linked list in the destructor? I know that we normally use delete after using new. Or can I just leave the contents of the constructor and destructor empty like this?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: The proper term is "member variables" (not "attributes"). Member variables which have constructors get their constructor run before your class's constructor (and their destructor run after your class's destructor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call constructor and destructors of std::list member explicitly. Compiler would handle these for you.

So yes, you can leave the contructor and destructors of this class empty.

Answer (score 1):

In your case it is `std::list`'s responsibility to allocate and de-allocate the memory so you need not do anything in the destructor. Leaving the constructor and destructor bodies empty will work fine and there will be no memory leak.